# CoefficientList not working

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials

My list of variables is

`var = {a1 Y1,a2 Y2,a1 Y1 Ym1,a2 Y2 Ym1,a1 Y1 Ym2,a2 Y2 Ym2}`

and the polynomial is

`poly = -2 a1 m^2 Y1-2 a1 Y1 Ym1-2 a2 m^2 Y2+a2 p^2 Y2-a2 Y2 Ym1-a2 Y2 Ym2+d`

However when I write

`CoefficientList[poly, vars]`

the output that I get is

`(((-2 a1 Y1 m^2-2 a2 Y2 m^2+d+a2 p^2 Y2-2 a1 Y1 Ym1-a2 Y2 Ym1-a2 Y2 Ym2)))`

why is this so ? On the other hand:

```
Coefficient[poly, {a1 Y1}]
```

gives the output

```
{-2 m^2-2 Ym1}
```

Comment: for `CoefficientList` your "variables" can not be products of symbols.  If you compare the docs for `Coefficient` and `CoefficientList` the difference in the second argument ( *form* vs *var* ) should be apparent.

Answer (score 1):

this may do what you want:
(Notice I reordered the var list with the three-factor terms first )

```
var = {a1 Y1 Ym1, a2 Y2 Ym1, a1 Y1 Ym2, a2 Y2 Ym2, a1 Y1, a2 Y2};
poly = -2 a1 m^2 Y1 - 2 a1 Y1 Ym1 - 2 a2 m^2 Y2 + a2 p^2 Y2 - 
   a2 Y2 Ym1 - a2 Y2 Ym2 + d;
{rem, coef} = 
    Fold[
     Simplify[#1 - #2 Sow@Coefficient[#1, #2 ]] & ,
      poly , var] // Reap
```

> {d, {{-2, -1, 0, -1, -2 m^2, -2 m^2 + p^2}}}

```
Total@Join[{rem}, First@coef var ] == poly  // Simplify
```

> True